# how to convert database null field value to decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have some database fields with datatype decimal but it's db null fields.
So, I want to do some condition with these fields but before I compare with with any other decimal value such as 0.00 I have to convert those fields in to decimal but I don't know how to convert database null fields in to decimal.

for example:
I have these two fields.

```
string ltl_net_rate = Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_freight_out_net_plus"].FieldValue;
string total_shipment_weight = Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_pick_ticket_weight"].FieldValue;
```

and then I want to do

```
if (ltl_netplus_rate_new < ltl_net_rate_new) then do something
if (ltl_net_rate_new < 0 || ltl_netplus_rate_new < 0) then do something
```

I used `Convert.Todecimal` but it's gave me error message that input string is not in correct format.

Then I knew that it's db null fields so Convert.Todecimal won't help.

Can any one please help me how can I handle this?

Comment: Add a check to see if its null. I would add how you could do that but I do not know what type Data or Fields or FieldValue is and how you are populating this. If you want more help I would recommend you add an [mcve] or search on DBNull check + whatever types you are using here.

Comment: `decimal something = decimal.TryParse(Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_freight_out_net_plus"].FieldValue?.ToString(), out decimal myValue) ? myValue : 0;` something along those lines (not knowing your types). Without a reproducible example it's still hard to give you a more concise example.

Comment: Does the `Nullable<T>` type move you forward?  `decimal? ltl_net_rate = ...`

Comment: This worked for me.
Thank you so much

Comment: Did you try the solution below it could be helpfull ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic extension method to resolve your problem by using the method below

```
    public static T DBValue<T>(this object dbValue)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbValue == DBNull.Value)
                return default;
            return (T)dbValue;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(dbValue, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for DbNull while you get the data from DB and if they are null assign a default value such as 0.00.

For an example check nulls as follow when you get the following data.

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_freight_out_net_plus"].FieldValue))
            {
                string ltl_net_rate = Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_freight_out_net_plus"].FieldValue;
            }
            else
            {
                string ltl_net_rate = 0.00;

            }



            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_pick_ticket_weight"].FieldValue))
            {
                string total_shipment_weight = Data.Fields["ufc_oe_pick_ticket_ud_wt_pick_ticket_weight"].FieldValue;
            }
            else
            {
                string total_shipment_weight = 0.00;
            }
```

Or else convert the string value to decimal inside the if statement at onece (or do it later)

```
decimal ltl_netplus_rate_new  = Convert.ToDecimal(ltl_net_rate);
```

Comment: @RaviPatel you are welcome. Up vote the answer if this was helpful. Thank you.